# OS Cache Implementation: Segmentation Fault when using malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm writing a code that handles cache request made by the OS, and when I'm trying to allocate memory for my cache, I'm getting a segmentation fault and I dont know why. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

```
struct item {
char *key; 
struct file_data *value; 
int ref_count;
int size; 
struct item *next; 
}; 

struct wc {
    int capacity; 
    struct item **table; 
};

struct cache {
    struct wc *cache_table; 
    struct queue *cache_queue;
    int size; 
};

    struct server {
        int nr_threads;
        int max_requests;
        int max_cache_size;
        int exiting;
        /* add any other parameters you need */
        pthread_t *thread_array;
    int *buffer; 
    int buffer_in; 
    int buffer_out; 
    struct cache *cache; 
};


/* creating & initializing a hash table */ 
struct cache *cache_init(void)
{
    struct cache *initialized_cache = (struct cache *)malloc(sizeof(struct cache)); 

/* seg faulting in the following line*/
    if( (initialized_cache->cache_table->table = malloc(MAX_CACHE_TABLE_SIZE * sizeof(struct item**))) == NULL){
        return NULL; 
    }
```

Comment: How is `cache.cache_table` being initialized?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
struct cache *initialized_cache = (struct cache *)malloc(sizeof(struct cache));
```

creates a heap object filled with uninitialized bytes.

This line:

```
if( (initialized_cache->cache_table->table = malloc...
```

Takes an *unitialized* pointer from within that object, and tries to dereference it.

*Of course* it crashes<sup>1</sup>.

You need to make `initialized_cache->cache_table` point *somewhere* before you can dereference it.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's not guaranteed that it crashes, it could write to some random memory corrupting your state elsewhere, and making the bug so much harder to find.

You are *lucky* it crashed.